# Spring Boot Starter project not working (error in pom.xml) when including Spring Cloud dependencies

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-tool-suite

When I create a new Spring Starter project in Spring Tool Suite, and include Spring Cloud dependencies, I get an error in pom.xml and the app does not run at all. In fact, I'm getting 82 errors, mostly "missing artifact". When I remove the cloud dependency but keep all other dependencies, it works fine, so it is definitely to do with cloud. This happens with cloud config and cloud bootstrap dependencies (I tried creating new projects with both individually, and each gives errors). I've even tried a few different versions of Spring Boot, and copied and pasted a pom.xml from an online course, and I always get the same errors.

EDIT:

This is the pom.xml generated when I create a Spring starter project with only cloud-config:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
            <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
        </parent>
        <groupId>com.in28minutes.microservices</groupId>
        <artifactId>limits-service-3</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
        <name>limits-service-3</name>
        <description>LimitsService for Microservices Project</description>


        <properties>
            <java.version>11</java.version>
            <spring-cloud.version>2020.0.0</spring-cloud.version>
        </properties>
    
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
            </dependency>
    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    
        <dependencyManagement>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                    <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                    <type>pom</type>
                    <scope>import</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </dependencyManagement>
    
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    
        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>spring-milestones</id>
                <name>Spring Milestones</name>
                <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            </repository>
        </repositories>
</project>
```

The errors are mostly "missing artifact" as well as:

- Test cannot be resolved to a type
- The container 'Maven Dependencies' references non existing library
- The import org.junit.jupiter cannot be resolved
- The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved

Comment: Can you post the errors?

Comment: And the versions and the pom. Not very helpful as described

Comment: This is the auto generated pom.xml when I make a new Spring starter project with just cloud-config:

Comment: Have you tried using the actual dependency versions from the course?

Comment: my guess is this is a local maven cache issue. Spring Cloud doesn't manage junit dependencies. Running a fresh project from start.spring.io with an identical pom.xml works.

Comment: I would recommend to delete the local maven cache (~/.m2/repository) and do a right click on the project, then "Maven -> Update Project...". This should download all the required dependencies again.

Comment: thanks, but even if I start a new project it doesn't work; there is no .m2 folder (probably because it fails the first time) and when I update the project the same thing happens...

Comment: Are you looking for the .m2 folder in the right place, it isn't in your project but in your user's home directory typically. If there is no m2 folder I would be very surprised anything works at all (with or without spring-cloud dependencies). That's why I think perhaps you might be looking in the wrong place for it.